# how to get the drawing graphic on picture box in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a PictureBox in a panel. I drew some graphics on PictureBox. 
I want to get those graphics on button clicking.  How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call paint event from a button click event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766600/how-to-call-paint-event-from-a-button-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.syncfusion.com/faq/windowsforms/faq_c3c.aspx) link. In particular the *46.9 How do I programmatically load, modify and save a bitmap?* section of that page.

You'll get the idea even though the code sample is in VB.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is **You have some graphics drawn over a PictureBox and you want a Image of those graphics on the click of a Button**,isn't it.I am not sure if this'll work but try it;

```
    private void ButtonGetImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (SourcePictureBox.Image != null)//Just to make sure it's not empty.
       {
         Bitmap graphic = new Bitmap(SourcePictureBox.Image);
          {
            //Add some logic to modify Image if you want.
            graphic.Save(@"F:\Image.bmp");//An appropriate path to save the file.
            graphic.Dispose();
          }
       }
    }
```