# How to call paint event from a button click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

I have a pictureBox with the event "paint" and I also got code in there to draw graphics.

such as:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, 10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

My question is. How to fire these events of from a button_click event? I searched alot on the web and found alot of awnsers like ".invalidate()" or ".Refresh()" and ".Update". But my assignment tells me that I need to do it with the .Refresh() method and the painting needs to be in a pictureBox.

What I notice from .Refresh() method. Is that it erases the pictureBox(draws the pictureBox how it was created on initialize). So firing off .Refresh method in a button did not work for me.

Any other suggestions how to fire off a paint event from a button?

Comment: what language? java, c#?

Comment: I made a quik example. I am talking about this:

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, 10, 10, 100, 100);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

Comment: Everytime I launch the application the blue ellipse is automatically drawn and the button has no function at the moment.

or am I seeing unclear here ;p?

Comment: You need to add a "state" variable, such that when you press the button, you have `drawNow = true;` and then in the PictureBox, you check that variable.  Or you draw into a bitmap and show that bitmap in the PictureBox.

Comment: Sorry for spamming comments. I wanted to let you know that I updated my question. In that way it is clearer then the bunch of text that I wrote

Comment: See @LarsTech comment - it will always paint the ellipse unless you tell it not to (or vice versa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, 10, 10, 100, 100);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your suggestion does.

Comment: It's always better to dispose of that graphic object you created, preferably in a using block.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking forever for this. I wanted to find out how to [how to get the drawing graphic on picture box in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967822/how-to-get-the-drawing-graphic-on-picture-box-in-c-sharp), but the provided answers where useless. This actually solved that problem because how the Image was setup. `pictureBox1.Image` will properly get the drawn graphics here.